# I'm unable to create a new FOLDER on my new drive

Tags: partitioning, mount

I installed a second hdd on my system. The bios picks it up OK. I used GParted to build a partition on it and format the partition. But -- I'm unable to build a partition on the drive. From /dev/sda1 I am unable to issue commands to /dev/sdb1. So I can't put a folder on /dev/sdb1. How do I do that?

Comment: Can you take a screenshot of your first and second hard drive, and upload in in imgur.com and then edit the post above and add those links of images in your original question above?

Comment: excuse me! It should read "I'm unable to build a FOLDER on my new drive.

Comment: Please edit your question and change it

Comment: What format is the sdb1 partition? Why do you say that you partitioned it, and then ask how to partition it? How/why are you trying to create a new folder from the `terminal` app?

Answer (score 1):

After partitioning your new drive, you have to mount the newly formatted partition to be able to use it. Mounting is normally done at system boot time, and it uses a file `/etc/fstab` to know what/where to mount disk partitions.

Take a look at your current `/etc/fstab` like so:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo cat /etc/fstab
```

You can edit this file to add the proper mounts for /dev/sdb1:

In `terminal`...

`sudo blkid` # to determine the UUID of /dev/sdb1

`sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bck` # to make a backup of this file

`sudo pico /etc/fstab` # edit the file

using the UUID that you found earlier... for an ext4 partition... add lines similar to this...

```
# mount for /dev/sdb1
UUID=enter_the_found_UUID_here /media/your_username/your_volume_name ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 1
```

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> # to save edits

<kbd>return</kbd> # to confirm filename to save to

<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> # to exit the editor

`sudo mount -a` # to mount the drive

Comment: I ran sudo blkid # and got this result:

Comment: @MykeFynke I don't see your blkid output. The proper command is only what's shown in blue highlighting, so `sudo blkid`. The #, and everything after, is only a comment so that you know what we're doing in that command.

Comment: WHAT checkmark icon?

Comment: /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="p4HJQA-YAyp-ljV1-niA6-0D67-Cnih-t7eOkm" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="838b443e-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="lvm2 pv" UUID="c219592f-fd8a-4750-a079-9dd267f3ff14" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="bakup" PARTUUID="6458063c-582f-44d9-9341-858fa0728c66"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2018-03-17-18-11-37-00" LABEL="Data disc (17 Mar 18)" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="00d1e1f1-26d4-4e84-8cf8-c996ccd805ff" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="7a186be5-b684-4434-9e8d-09ad3d416f19" TYPE="swap"

Comment: I found the grey checkmark and checked it. Now it is blue. I still don't know what to do.  I ran sudo blkid and tried to send you the result but this system you got says my answer is too long by 44 characters. WTF?

Comment: @MykeFynke as per my instruction, you only needed to click the grey checkmark icon if my answer solved your problem. You might click it again to make it grey again, and then come back later when your problem is solved. The blkid output should be edited into your original question. Please delete your previous blkid comment. It looks like you tried to create sdb1 as an lvm drive, and then created a ext4 partition on it? That's not correct.

Comment: /dev/loop0: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop1: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/sda1: UUID="p4HJQA-YAyp-ljV1-niA6-0D67-Cnih-t7eOkm" TYPE="LVM2_member" PARTUUID="838b443e-01"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="lvm2 pv" UUID="c219592f-fd8a-4750-a079-9dd267f3ff14" TYPE="ext4" PARTLABEL="bakup" PARTUUID="6458063c-582f-44d9-9341-858fa0728c66"
/dev/sr0: UUID="2018-03-17-18-11-37-00" LABEL="Data disc (17 Mar 18)" TYPE="iso9660"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: UUID="00d1e1f1-26d4-4e84-8cf8-c996ccd805ff" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-swap_1: UUID="7a186be5-b684-4434-9e8d-09ad3d416f19" TYPE="swap"

Comment: I don't have enough reputation  to move to chat. I LOVE this ridiculous software you got.

Comment: I didn't ask you to go to chat. You posted the same blkid output as before. Delete both comments that show the blkid output. Then click the **edit** under your original question, and paste the blkid output there. This "ridiculous" software isn't mine. It's done by the askubuntu folks. Just follow the simple instructions.

Comment: No offense but I can't work with you. In fact, I can't work at all on this website. It's got WAY too many rules -- like how many characters I can use -- about format. It's a crippled venue as far as I'm concerned. Thanks for trying but I'm out of here. I'll get an answer someplace else.